# Files no longer compile ("I cannot write pdf") in TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker

I was working on my report for a few days in TeXMaker. I compiled it, went for lunch, came back and now it doesn't work.

Compiling takes forever, and it doesn't complete - either ends in error ("I cannot write pdf") or it just hangs up. I get the error "File not found" when I just start up, but it opens up fine, so it is obviously found. It doesn't include any other files except my bibliography.

I tried:

- Starting/restarting TeXMaker -> even killed the processes which for
  some reason don't stop once TeXMaker is closed.
- Restarted my computer
- Resaved the file in another directory
- Pasted code into another file
- Checked that I'm admin (I ran TeXMaker as admin too)
- Just reinstalled TeXMaker, still doesn't work...

I am the only user on this computer, I have access to all drives. PDF isn't open anywhere else. In fact nothing else is really open.

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Something we can compile to see where the error lies?

Comment: I found it... `\begin{tabular}{ C{1.25 in} C{1 in} *4{C{ 0.75 in}}}\toprule[1.5pt]`. There was a missing { in that line, which apparently really breaks everything forever without being a normal error. It hangs up pdflatex, and even cleaning the project (deleting all generated TeX files) doesn't fix it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to stem from unmatched braces.

Comment: ... Off-topic from what exactly? I am using a TeX compiler with a TeX editor. The compiler doesn't complain about missing braces, it complains about either not being able to write to the pdf, or it simply hangs. I don't know if that's the desired behaviour, because it sure doesn't seem like the appropriate response to something anyone could do. When I asked the question, my guess was the environment specifically and that I broke the pdf compiler somehow. If I knew it was brackets, I wouldn't have this problem, and I wouldn't ask.